# MVC 5 DB first EF displaying view model with 3 classes(DAL)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a MVC 5 with EF (DB first approach) application I am creating. The issue I am having is to correctly display the list with the correct data in each column.

I have 3 classes in my DAL:

```
public partial class MenuItem
{
    public int MenuItemID { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Item Name")]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Description")]
    public string description { get; set; }
    public int catID { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}

public partial class PricingTier
{
    public PricingTier()
    {
        this.MenuItemsPricingTiers = new HashSet<MenuItemsPricingTier>();
    }

    public int PricingTierID { get; set; }
    public string tierName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<MenuItemsPricingTier> MenuItemsPricingTiers { get; set;}
}

public partial class MenuItemsPricingTier
{
    public int MenuItemPricingTierID { get; set; }
    public int itemID { get; set; }
    public int tierID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> price { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> sortOrder { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> hide { get; set; }

    public virtual PricingTier PricingTier { get; set; }
 }
```

The view I require is to list menu items (filtered by a selected category id passed to the controller) with a column for each pricing tier.  If the menu item has a menu item pricing tier, I need the price to be displayed in that column. The issue is that each menu item may or may not have a menu item pricing tier.  Also, the tables were poorly designed as there is no foreign key between the menu item pricing tier and the menu items.

I tried to create a viewmodel class to display this, but I cannot seem to tie things together. Here is the view model class:

```
public class MenuItemViewModel
{
    public MenuItemViewModel(MenuItem menuitem, IEnumerable<MenuItemsPricingTier>                       menuitemspricingtiers)
    {
        this.menuitem = menuitem;
        this.menuitemspricingtiers = menuitemspricingtiers.Where(x=>x.itemID == menuitem.MenuItemID);
    }
    public MenuItem menuitem { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<MenuItemsPricingTier> menuitemspricingtiers { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index(int catID)
    {
        var menuitems = db.MenuItems.Include(m => m.Category);

        IEnumerable<MenuGridData> viewmodel = new IEnumerable<MenuGridData>();

        foreach (MenuItem mi in menuitems) {
            // add to viewmodel using repository.GetMenuItem(mi.MenuItemID) ??
        }


        IEnumerable<MenuItemsPricingTier> menuitemspricingtiers = repository.GetMenuItemsPricingTiers();

        return View(viewmodel);
    }
```

I am not sure if this is the correct approach on how I should go about this. I have been playing around with this without much success. I would appreciate any help here, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should create dedicated view model classes.  You mention that each MenuItem may or may not have a PriceItem, why not do this for your view model:

```
 public class MenuItemViewModel
 {
     public MenuItem MenuItem { get; set; }
     public List<PriceItem> PriceItems { get; set; }
 }
```

I could go on with that view model, the point is don't try and force your EF model classes as view models.  create specific view models that contain everything you need.  Sometimes people write entirely new models for the view and then convert to the Domain/EF models via the controller.

Comment: Maybe I am over thinking things here, but each MenuItem has multiple pricing tiers(meaning multiple prices).  So each row consists of one menu item with several columns(pricing tiers) that may or may not be populated, depending upon the data from the menuitempricingtiers entity.

Comment: you are not over thinking... just change the view model then.. I will edit my answer.